# Conditional join result count in a large dataframe

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, hive, apache-pig

I have a data set of about 100m rows, 4gb, containing two lists like these:

```
Seed
a
r
apple
hair
brush
tree

Phrase
apple tree       
hair brush
```

I want to get the count of unique matched 'Phrase's for each unique 'Seed'. So for example, the seed 'a' is contained in both 'apple tree' and 'hair brush', so it's 'Phrases_matched_count' should be '2'. Matches are just using partial patches (i.e. a 'string contains' match, does not need to be a regex or anything complex).

```
Seed    Phrases_matched_count
a       2
r       2
apple   1
hair    1
brush   1
tree    1
```

I have been trying to find a way to do this using Apache Pig (on a small Amazon EMR cluster), and Python Pandas (the data set just about fits in memory), but just can't find a way to do this without looping through every row for each unique 'seed', which will take very long, or a cross product of the tables, which will use too much memory.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using built-in `contains` but I'm not sure of its scalability on an important number of data.

```
# Test data
seed = pd.Series(['a','r', 'apple', 'hair', 'brush', 'tree'])
phrase = pd.Series(['apple tree', 'hair brush'])
# Creating a DataFrame with seeds as index and phrases as columns
df = pd.DataFrame(index=seed, columns=phrase)
# Checking if each seed is contained in each phrase
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.index.str.contains(x.name), axis=1)
# Getting the result
df.sum(axis=1)

# The result
a        2
r        2
apple    1
hair     1
brush    1
tree     1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this doesn't address the problem. I'm not trying to count maches within rows - I'm trying to count how many matches there are from each unique Seed, to all possible unique Phrases. I.e., down the whole 'Phrase' column. Hence the problem of scalability. Sorry if that wasn't clear - I've made a couple of edits to try and clarify in the original post.

Comment: No problem. I have modified my answer, tell me if it helps.

Comment: Still not quite what I'm looking for, because the complete matching between 'Seed' and 'Phrase' is not yet done. What I showed is just an incomplete correspondance between the two lists. Again, sorry if that wasn't clear - I've edited the original post to try to make it clearer that there are two lists, and it's a all-vs-all search problem. That all vs all search for string matches is really the most difficult step.

Comment: My last try, then I give up :-(